# Jquery Spin Button

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there any good Jquery spin button that only allow numbers and respond to up/down keys as well as the mouse wheel ?

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this will work for you:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Spinner

the problem is that the above only works with the jquery UI 1.9 milstone release.  This one, however, should work:

http://www.jgeppert.com/jquery-spinner/

Comment: thanks jjross the spinner looks great and I really want to use, but don't know how to download it, cause I have to download, right?

Comment: Try here.  Just be aware that this spinner above is part of the jquery UI 1.9 milestone release.  http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/11/jquery-ui-1-9-milestone-3-spinner/

Comment: and would that mean that I can't use with this jQuery UI 1.8.7? I tried adding this file: jquery.ui.spinner.js to my js directory, but it didn't work at all :( , if it is possible to use it with jQuery UI 1.8.7, would you mind telling me which files do I need to copy into my js direcory?

Comment: thanks jjross, I tried to use http://www.jgeppert.com/jquery-spinner/ , but I couldn't get it to work, I think it's because this plugin uses jquery 1.4.3  and jquery-ui-1.8.5  and I use jquery 1.4.4.js  and jquery-ui-1.8.7.js

Comment: I wouldn't expect a point release to make that much of a difference.  What issues did you have?

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful

http://www.egrappler.com/contents/smartspin/demo/spinner.htm

that respond on up/down keys and mouse wheel scroll as well.